# Removing DE and installing a new DE

Tags: desktop-environments

I have the following DE installed in my ubuntu 16.04.

gnome-classic.desktop

gnome.desktop

ubuntustudio.desktop

xfce.desktop

I want to completely remove them all and and install a new one.
I got to know that removing DE is a messy work and so if i had to try out a DE i should have done it in virtual box. So how do i do it in Virtual box. I'd like to check unity and cinnamon before installing. How do I go about it ?

output of systemd-analyse critical-chain

graphical.target @30.738s
└─multi-user.target @30.738s
  └─getty.target @30.737s
    └─getty@tty1.service @30.736s
      └─rc-local.service @30.710s +3ms
        └─network-online.target @30.693s
          └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @21.209s +9.483s
            └─NetworkManager.service @18.485s +2.714s
              └─dbus.service @14.682s
                └─basic.target @14.441s
                  └─sockets.target @14.441s
                    └─snapd.socket @14.276s +157ms
                      └─sysinit.target @14.276s
                        └─apparmor.service @11.050s +3.226s
                          └─local-fs.target @11.040s
                            └─boot.mount @10.761s +277ms
                              └─systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-758af2ae\x2d5c6
                                └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-758af2ae\x2d5c6d\x2d4819\x

Comment: There's no need to "check it out". DE's shouldn't hurt your system. Simply install the DE you wish to try, sign out, and select the desktop environment and log in. To install Unity, for example: "sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop^" (include the caret). Sign out and select it on sign in.

Comment: @patrickyi, but i do see some weird things before the welcome screen (for moments, spitting out error messages, and then the welcome screen comes). I didn' have it when i had only gnome. May be thats because of the additional DE's i installed ??

Comment: No, that is common and unfortunately throws off people who are new to Linux. I have several errors that are listed relating to acpi before the Desktop Environment loads, but they really aren't issues.

Comment: My booting time is really high, when i run this command,  this was the optput   $ systemd-analyze 
Startup finished in 2.703s (kernel) + 56.631s (userspace) = 59.335s  ny any chance is does it have anything to do with multiple DE's ?? If now, what could be the probable cause ?

Comment: Use the command: "systemd-analyze critical-chain" and post the results in the question.